# RCBO Test button stuck in pressed position

Tags: electrical-panel, safety, protection, testing

I pressed the Test button on this RCBO and it worked as expected, tripping the RCBO, but the button got stuck.
It wouldn't spring back to its normal position.
The home owner said it wasn't pressed by anybody in many years. People either forgot, or were not aware of the good practice of pushing the test button regularly.

When I tried to flip the levers up to the ON position, they would immediately flip back down, because the test button being stuck, I believe.

I left it for about 30 minutes, and when I came back and flipped the levers up again, they remained up, and everything seemed to work fine, but the Test button is still stuck.
And now, it only needs a very slight push and it trips the breakers.

This is how it looked before:
[image: rcbo before]

And this is how it looks now:
[image: rcbo after]

You can see the half-disk shaped black button the left side appears to be stuck.

The test button of the "DPS-MN", which I believe is an Overvoltage protection ("DPS" I think stands for *"Dispozitiv de Protectie la Supratensiune"* in Romanian language, which translated to English would be *"Overvoltage Protection Device"*), on the right, worked fine. It tripped the breakers and returned to the normal position.

Is it normal for this RCBO model to behave like that? I couldn't find any information about its test button in the datasheet. Other than this schematic, which I only partly understand (or think I do).
[image: rcbo schematic]

Is there something else that needs to be done for the test button to return, that I am missing?

Could it just be like that because of its age and the degradation of the materials? It is mounted outside, on the house wall, sealed against dust and water, but in direct sunlight half of the day. And was exposed to temperature changes for many winters and summers.

It seems to be working even with the button stuck like this, but is it safe?

Should I try to poke at it with something or pull it back somehow?

Comment: You don't go from "Tripped" to "ON".  You always switch from "Tripped" to "OFF" and then back up to "ON".  That may help.  The button is a simple electrical pushbutton switch, it connects Line Hot to Load Neutral through a resistor.  It is not mechanical in any way and does not connect to the throw mechanism.   Note that 300mA threshold is *very slack* and is functionally worthless for human safety.  Western Europe uses 30mA which has some limited value for human safety. North America uses 5mA but can only apply it on a per-circuit basis because it's too sensitive.

Comment: They do not last forever, so probably better to replace than fooling around with it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's right. I've updated the question to include the schematic from the datasheet. The test button is indeed represented as a simple pushbutton, that should open as soon as you lift your finger off. I'm sorry, it's not clear to me what you mean by switching from "Tripped" to "OFF". On this model these two states are identical. There's no way to know if the levers are down (with the text "OFF" visible on them) because the Test button was pushed, a leakage current > 300ma detected, overcurrent > 20A, or manually flipped down. How do I go from Tripped to OFF?

Comment: @RobertLee It's not all that apparent on North American breakers either, which drives people crazy.  Push the handle down all the way to get to "off".  What I'm saying is if you are having trouble getting it to go from "tripped" to "on", try cycling it through "off". I know that sounds like 1990s computer help desk advice lol...   However if the breaker will hold on, it sounds like the test button is working just a bit sticky.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I see. :D Oh, yes very sticky. I am worried that the stickiness, which makes the Test button to rest kind of "in between" its normal states (or at least closer to the pushed state), could cause an electric arc, or interfere with the RCBOs normal functions. If I understood the diagram correctly, it creates a closed circuit from Live to Neutral, but bypassing the coils, causing a current difference similar to a ground fault. I also see a resistor there (perhaps around 500ohm, to cause a leak of > 300ma @230V), so arcing should be less likely I hope.

Comment: @RobertLee I wouldn't worry. For one thing there is a high value resistor there, and for another if the switch did short, it'll cause an instant trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like weather has simply aged the unit and the button is now sticky.

If you can get another GE breaker out of that same line, it will dock right up to the shunt trip unit to the right of it. (the one marked "Tele LE") so you can avoid having to replace that also.  I gather the overvoltage detector actuates the shunt trip?

However, in selecting a replacement, I call your attention to the "300mA" marking on the breaker.  **That indicates it is a *very, very poor* RCD**.  Europeans use RCD for two reasons:

- To detect arcing between wires - however only arcing from live to earth or neutral to earth.
- Shock protection for humans. The ideal detection threshold for this task is 5mA.  However all the circuits in a home will often sum up to more leakage than that, so the European compromise is a 30mA threshold and to use one unit for the entire apartment or large part of it.

This 300mA threshold is absolutely useless for human protection, and is of degraded value for arcing detection.  I would have a pro revisit the need for 300mA... or change it to 30mA to conform to EU standards or even 5-10mA protection if it warrants excellent human protection.

Or if arc fault protection is the primary concern, go with a modern arc-fault detector, with a microprocessor doing signal analysis of the voltage and current on the wires, "listening" for arcing.

Comment: At least in the UK there is another reason for using RCDs, to provide disconnection for earth faults in circumstances where this cannot be provided by overcurrent protection devices. For example TT systems. 

Advising people to remove RCDs without understanding their purpose in the context of local regulations is totally reckless.

Comment: This RCBO is what the supplier company installed some time ago. The panel has a seal on it, and only an authorized electrician would be allowed to open it I suppose. However, this is not the only protection for the entire house. There's another panel further down the line which has a better RCBO installed (30ma, Type A leakage waveform detection). And another 10ma for the washing machine circuit, which also includes the fridge and microwave oven).

Comment: I cannot tell for sure what actuates the Shunt Trip, but my best guess is the overvoltage protection. There are no fire alarm, smoke detectors, or any sensors like that. Could be a remote disconnect functionality for the supplier company in case the bills are not paid on time? :D

Comment: @PeterGreen This is indeed something like TT, but even worse, the house doesn't have earthing at all. No ground rods. No green-yellow wires. So it's rather a TNC? RCDs are indeed the primary protection for ground faults in this case.

Comment: @PeterGreen good point. Edited to remove that.

Comment: @RobertLee A shunt trip module is "muscle" that trips the breaker when something else commands it.  Most likely, that "something else" is the high voltage detector.  High voltage detection is important because if you lose a neutral on 3-phase distribution, voltage can roam as high as 400V.  The lack of local earth spikes and bonding makes that much more acute.  I suspect you have TN-S (which may actually be TN-C-S behind the curtain). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZVx7GbAwlg&t=1182s

Comment: Of course, 30mA -RCDs do save users from electrocutions. It is the product of current x time which defines the danger zones, see any document about GFCIs/RCDs. 
Regardless of the zones, 10mA-RCDs @230 V corresponding to ca. 5mA@120V (linearity assumed) may be even less safe in practice, since people may tend to remove them after many nuisance trips. 30mA@230V RCDs are not only used in Europe, but also in many Asian, African and South American countries.

Comment: Another important point is, that according European statistics, RCDs save more people from dangers caused by fires then electrocutions. A ground wire is nearly always close to Hot and Neutral wires in the standard NYM- installation cables. If a cable gets damaged by drilling into a wall (very often mistake, which may not be obvious), it is very likely that the cable gets very hot at that location. The insulation of all 3 wires fails, and current from Hot to Ground will exceed 30mA before a fire starts.